# Using CygWin in ConEmu

Tags: console, cygwin, conemu

This is a simple question that might reveal my lack of understanding of the ConEmu console...

I recently installed ConEmu and CygWin to get nice command line interface setup to mimic my OS X and Ubuntu set ups.

I want to be able to `ls` and use linux style commands in ConEmu from startup of the application and I was of the opinion that the CygWin task in ConEmu would achieve this linkage.

What am I doing incorrectly that is preventing me from using CygWin commands in ConEmu such as `ls`? PowerShell, annoyingly, seems to link `ls` to `dir` perfectly well ...

Attached is my task in the ConEmu settings
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a hotkey to CygWin Bash and then executing the hotkey created a new tab that I could use the CygWin console within.

Previously I had thought all consoles would be combined into the initial tab with all commands available. However, this is not really viable as for CygWin, for instance, there is a completely different drive set up to emulate linux.

Answer (score 2):

I waas able to use Cygwin with Conemu just adding the same command that cygwin adds on the desktop link.

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -
```

And it worked just the same as it works if you execute the link directly.

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not relate to ConEmu at all.

Learn about `PATH` environment variable and how OS executes commands. Learn about `PowerShell aliases`...

In brief. When you run `PowerShell` task the `ls.exe` is not executed if you run `ls` from PS prompt.

Comment: Thanks I had suspected that `ls` was an alias for `dir`,  but this doesn't really help me use CygWin in ConEmu

Comment: As I said, it doesn't relate to ConEmu. Delete or replace alias, or add cygwin binaries to PATH.

Comment: You're saying "use cygwin in ConEmu" but talking about PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

It should automatically support. Try resetting and reloading defaults , if both dont work. Check the path properly.If that also doesnt work, try adding cygwin.bat instead sh.exe. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I tried cygwin.bat but received `'c:\cygwin64\bin\cygwin.bat' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable programme or batch file`